OCD affected my undergrad grades for the first two years but I picked up later, what are my chances at a good graduate school?
I am from India and I have a bachelor's in Electrical Engineering. I had bad grades for the first two years of my undergrad when I was struggling with OCD, specifically around 2.66/4.0. I learnt to deal with the OCD and improved my grades from the third year onwards with a cumulative of 3.1/4.0 at the end.The grades have a straight upward trajectory with 3.7/4.0 in the last semester.
Also I had taken two elective courses for computer science in which I scored 4.0/4.0
I am planning to apply for a master's in computer science program. I also have 4 years of work experience as a data engineer.
Do I have a chance at good schools? How do I inform that admission committee that my first two years were an exception due to a medical issue and ask them to focus on later grades.

Can you define "good schools"?

I am not sure, what would be the best school I can aim for?

In the US, at least, the focus will automatically be on your later grades. It is recognized that people can struggle early, for many reasons, and improve later. The later, advanced, courses are also generally more important for grad study and for prediction of success there. And a trending toward perfect late record is pretty good evidence.
However, in the US, grades are only one factor, with letters of recommendation being especially important. Get good letters from faculty who know you well. And, if a very supportive letter writer mentions, simply, that you overcame OCD and left it behind, it would probably be better than if you mention it yourself.
If you do mention it, don't give it more than a sentence, such as to state that you overcame it and moved on.
You might not need to mention OCD specifically in any written materials, but be prepared to discuss it if asked in any interview.
